# Sequelize Relationships

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

Been attempting to work through sequelize relationships today but am getting stuck at the first hurdle.

```
var models = require('../models');

var users = models.users;

users.hasMany(models.images, {as: 'Images'});
console.log(users.getImages());
```

I see no reason why this doesn't work and I'm copying it almost line by line from the examples.

I get the error 'getImages() is not a function'. The method doesn't exist.

I'm probably been stupid, but would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access your `class` ( table ) instead of your `instance` ( row ) images.

The right direction would be :

```
users.hasMany( models.images, { as : "Images" } );
users.findOne({}).then( function( user ) { 
    // User is our instance ( the row, that actually has other rows related ) 
    user.getImages() 
} );
```